# How to build a multi-class convolutional neural network with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement a U-Net with Keras with Tensorflow backend for an image segmentation task. I have images of size (128,96) as input to the network together with mask images of size (12288,6) since they are flattened. I have 6 different classes (0-5) which gives the second part of the mask images' shape. They have been encoded to one-hot labels using the to_categorical() function. At the moment I use just one input image and also use the same one as validation and test data.

I would like the U-Net to perform image segmentation, where class 0 corresponds to the background. When I now train my U-Net only for a few epochs (1-10), the resulting predicted mask image seems to just give random classes to each pixel. When I train the network longer (50+ epochs), all pixels are classified as background. Since I train and test using the same image, I find this very weird as I was expedting the network to overtrain. How can I fix this problem? Could there be something wrong with the way I give mask images and the real images to the network?

I have tried giving weights to the network manually to put less emphasis on background than the other classes and have tried different combinations of losses, different ways of shaping the mask image and many other things but nothing gave good results.

Below is the code of my network. It is based on the U-Net taken from [this repository](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/unet.py). I managed to train it for the two class case with good results but I don't know how to extend it to more classes now.

```
def get_unet(self):

    inputs = Input((128, 96,1))
    #Input shape=(?,128,96,1)

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
      kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', input_shape=(None,128,96,6))(inputs)
    #Conv1 shape=(?,128,96,64)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
          kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    #Conv1 shape=(?,128,96,64)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    #pool1 shape=(?,64,48,64)


    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
         kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    #Conv2 shape=(?,64,48,128)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
         kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    #Conv2 shape=(?,64,48,128)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    #Pool2 shape=(?,32,24,128)

    conv5 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
         kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv5 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
         kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
        kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv5))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
         kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
         kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)


    up9 = Conv2D(64, (2,2), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
        kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
        kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
        kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(6, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same',
        kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(6, (1,1), activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
    conv10 = Reshape((128*96,6))(conv10)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-5), loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
          metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong with my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, also with a U-net for segmentation. It tends to do this:

- Go to totally black or totally white
- After a lot of time in which the loss seems to be frozen, it finds it's way.

I also use the "train just one image" method to find that convergence, then adding the other images is ok.

But I had to try a lot of times, and the only time it worked pretty fast was when I used:

- final activation = 'sigmoid'
- loss = 'binary_crossentropy'

But I wasn't using "relu" anywhere...perhaps that influences a little the convergence speed...? Thinking about "relu", which has only 0 or positive results, there is a big region in this function that does not have a gradient. Maybe having lots of "relu" activations creates a lot of "flat" areas without gradients? (Must think better about it to confirm)

Try a few times (and have patience to wait for many many epochs) with different weight initializations.

There is a chance that your learning rate is too big too.

---

About `to_categorical()`: have you tried to plot/print your masks? Do they really seem like what you expect them to?

Comment: thanks for your answer! I will try out your suggestions! I am using the sigmoid activation with the binary crossentropy loss. What kind of activation did you use for the hidden layers?
About the `to_categorical()` function, I am plotting the masks and they look fine when converting to the one-hot labels and back. But I am not very sure if that is the right format of labels for the Keras network.

Comment: The idea is exactly to **plot the one-hot encoded** masks (not the original masks). `One-hot`, as it says, usually has **only one** value as 1, and all the rest is 0. That would never make a mask (you need lots of 1's to make a mask), but I'm not used to the `to_categorical()` function to know exactly what it's doing. But you probably shouldn't have to use it with masks, you need every channel to have lots of 1's. If your maks are from images with values between 0 and 255, all you have to do is divide the images by 255.

Comment: I don't think, I understand what you mean. I have masks of size 128x96x6, where 128x96 is the pixel size of the images and I have 6 different classes. In each channel I have zeros and ones, always indicating if a pixel belongs to the respective class of the channel. So you say I should not one-hot encode the mask images?

Comment: Your idea of how to organize the data for masks is perfect. If what you're describing is `y_training` exactly as you pass it to the `fit()` method, then you don't need to worry about what I said. I was just suggesting that you plot (actually see an image formed by) one or two channels from samples in `y_training` data. (It sounded like you were plotting the original masks, before using `to_categorical()`). The intention was just to check if `to_categorical()` is actually giving you valid masks.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my `y_training` is a flattened version of the masks I described, so instead of being of size 128x96x6, it is of size (128*96)x6. But I have also plotted the channels separately and they show exactly the part of the mask they are supposed to. Can you remember approximately how many epochs the training of your unet needed? I have run it for 5000 now but that did not make a difference.

Comment: Ok :) ---  Unfortunately I'm not sure about what happens. I suggest you create the model again, and maybe not use the `he_normal` initialization? In my case, it was quite random, sometimes I got luck, sometimes I got stuck. I got success using `optimizer='adam'`. I'm not sure if using the string `'adam'` is different from creating an `Adam` object. When I used the object, I was trying to use bigger learning rates, and it got worse.

Comment: It just happened to me.... (updated the answer a little)... "Relu" activations have flat areas (negative values are eliminated). Perhaps having lots of "relu" could create lots of areas without any gradient to descent, depending on your luck.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Daniel, your suggestions helped me in the end to get the Unet to work. I managed to get results that did not just classify the whole image as background when running 500+ epochs. Also, instead of using `kernel_initializer='he_normal'`, `kernel_initializer='zeros'`or `kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.07)` worked for me. I used 'sigmoid' activation function and `loss='binary_crossentropy'`. I kept the 'relu' activation for all the hidden convolutional layers. I noticed that my network will sometimes be stuck in a local minimum where the loss does not improve anymore, so I need to restart.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your prediction layer which as far as I know must be a dense layer and not a convolutional layer.
Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Flo. Can you specify what you mean by adding a prediction layer? I am following the architecture of [U-Net: Convolutional Networks for Biomedical Image Segmentation](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) and I don't know how to add a dense layer for prediction to the network.