# Loss not evolving when using skip connections

Tags: python-2.7, keras, convolution, loss, deep-residual-networks

I'm trying to implement this paper in Keras : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.09056.pdf which uses Conv-Deconv with skip connections to create an image denoising network. My network is working pretty well if I make symmetrical skip connections between corresponding Conv-Deconv layers but if I add a connection between the input and the output (like in the paper), my network is impossible to train. Is it me that don't understand the paper ?

> "However, our network learns for the additive corruption from the input since there is a skip connection between the input and the output of the network"

Here is the network described in the paper :

[image]

And here is my network :

```
input_img = Input(shape=(None,None,3))

############################
####### CONVOLUTIONS #######
############################

c1 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(input_img)
a1 = Activation('relu')(c1)

c2 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a1)
a2 = Activation('relu')(c2)

c3 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a2)
a3 = Activation('relu')(c3)

c4 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a3)
a4 = Activation('relu')(c4)

c5 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a4)
a5 = Activation('relu')(c5)

############################
###### DECONVOLUTIONS ######
############################

d1 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(a5)
a6 = Activation('relu')(d1)

m1 = add([a4, a6])
a7 = Activation('relu')(m1)

d2 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(a7)
a8 = Activation('relu')(d2)

m2 = add([a3, a8])
a9 = Activation('relu')(m2)

d3 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(a9)
a10 = Activation('relu')(d3)

m3 = add([a2, a10])
a11 = Activation('relu')(m3)

d4 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3))(a11)
a12 = Activation('relu')(d4) 

m4 = add([a1, a12])
a13 = Activation('relu')(m4)

d5 = Conv2DTranspose(3, (3, 3))(a13)
a14 = Activation('relu')(d5)

m5 = add([input_img, a14]) # Everything goes well without this line
out = Activation('relu')(m5)

model = Model(input_img, out) 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

If I train it, here is what I get :

```
Epoch 1/10
31250/31257 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0015
Current PSNR: 28.1152534485

31257/31257 [==============================] - 89s - loss: 0.0015 - val_loss: 0.0015
Epoch 2/10
31250/31257 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0015
Current PSNR: 28.1152534485

31257/31257 [==============================] - 89s - loss: 0.0015 -  val_loss: 0.0015
Epoch 3/10
31250/31257 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0015
Current PSNR: 28.1152534485

31257/31257 [==============================] - 89s - loss: 0.0015 -   val_loss: 0.0015
Epoch 4/10
31250/31257 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0015
Current PSNR: 28.1152534485

31257/31257 [==============================] - 89s - loss: 0.0015 - val_loss: 0.0015
Epoch 5/10
31250/31257 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0015
Current PSNR: 28.1152534485
```

What is wrong with my network ?

Comment: But your loss is pretty low. Why do you claim that it's not learning?

Comment: Because the loss does not evolve ? Is it not supposed to be minimised progressively ?

Answer (score 0):

The activation `'relu'` **never returns a negative value**.

Since you're adding the input to the output (`a14`) and you need to "denoise" (**remove** noise), it's certainly expected that the output (`a14`) contains both **positive and negative** values. (You want to darken light spots and lighten dark spots).

Because of that, the activation in `a14` cannot be `'relu'`. It must be something both positive and negative, and capable of reaching the range of the noise. Probably a `'tanh'` or a custom activation. If your input goes from 0 to 1, a `'tanh'` would probably be the best option.

(Not sure about the previous layers, perhaps a few of them using `'tanh'`  would make the process easier)

---

Sometimes those long convolutional networks do get stuck, I'm training a U-net here, and it took a while to make it converge. When it gets stuck, sometimes it's better to build the model again (new weight initalizations) and try over.

See details here: [How to build a multi-class convolutional neural network with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939446/how-to-build-a-multi-class-convolutional-neural-network-with-keras)