# Unable to compile keras model for multi-class prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

My question is a slight extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45939446/8100895). I have images of size **256x256** and my masks are of dimension **65536x4** because I flattened (reshaped array) it and I have 4 classes, hence the 4. 
Now, I would like to train a U-net to do multi-class prediction. Here's my code:

```
import os
import sys
import random
import warnings
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tqdm import tqdm
from itertools import chain
from skimage.io import imread, imshow, imread_collection, concatenate_images, imsave
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.morphology import label
import cv2

from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model 


import tensorflow as tf

# Set some parameters
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
IMG_CHANNELS = 3
mask_dim = 256*256
TRAIN_IM = './train_im/'
TRAIN_MASK = './train_mask/'
num_training = len(os.listdir(TRAIN_IM))
num_test = len(os.listdir(TEST_PATH))
# Get and resize train images
X_train = np.zeros((num_training, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS), dtype=np.uint8)
Y_train = np.zeros((num_training, mask_dim, 4), dtype=np.bool)
print('Getting and resizing train images and masks ... ')
sys.stdout.flush()

#load training images
for count, filename in tqdm(enumerate(os.listdir(TRAIN_IM)), total=num_training):
    img = imread(os.path.join(TRAIN_IM, filename))[:,:,:IMG_CHANNELS]
    img = resize(img, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
    X_train[count] = img
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    mask_name = name + '_mask' + ext    
    mask = cv2.imread(os.path.join(TRAIN_MASK, mask_name))[:,:,:1]
    mask = np.squeeze(mask)
    Y_train[count] = mask
# Build U-Net model
''' ...import VGG16 layers to use pretrained weights...'''


width = 32
c1 = Conv2D(width, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (s)
c1 = Conv2D(width, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

c2 = Conv2D(width*2, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (p1)
c2 = Conv2D(width*2, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

c3 = Conv2D(width*4, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (p2)
c3 = Conv2D(width*4, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c3)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

c4 = Conv2D(width*8, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (p3)
c4 = Conv2D(width*8, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c4)
p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

c5 = Conv2D(width*16, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (p4)
c5 = Conv2D(width*16, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c5)

u6 = Conv2DTranspose(width*8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
u6 = concatenate([u6, c4, ll['block4_conv3']])
c6 = Conv2D(width*8, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (u6)
c6 = Conv2D(width*8, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c6)

u7 = Conv2DTranspose(width*4, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
u7 = concatenate([u7, c3, ll['block3_conv3']])
c7 = Conv2D(width*4, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (u7)
c7 = Conv2D(width*4, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c7)

u8 = Conv2DTranspose(width*2, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
u8 = concatenate([u8, c2, ll['block2_conv2']])
c8 = Conv2D(width*2, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (u8)
c8 = Conv2D(width*2, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c8)

u9 = Conv2DTranspose(width, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
u9 = concatenate([u9, c1, ll['block1_conv2']], axis=3)
c9 = Conv2D(width, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (u9)
c9 = Conv2D(width, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same') (c9)

outputs = Conv2DTranspose(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = bce_dice, metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(patience=20, verbose=1)
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('model-dsbowl2018-1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0, batch_size=1, epochs=100, 
                    callbacks=[earlystopper, checkpointer])
```

As I suspected, I'm not able to properly feed the ground truth. But I have no idea how to work around this problem. How exactly would I tell the network to treat each of the dimensions of the ground truth as its own class?

The error produced was the following:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 65536, 4) for Tensor 'conv2d_transpose_20_target:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, ?)'

**Update**

The accepted answer below does seem to fix the above issue, but it doesn't let me load the weights using `model.load_weights('model-dsbowl2018-1.h5')` 
as it gives me the following error:

> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 1 and 32. Shapes are [1,1,4,32] and [32,1,1,1]. for 'Assign_148' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [1,1,4,32], [32,1,1,1].

**Update Solved** When training multi-class segmentation network, you must have at least 2 images. A single image for some reason isn't sufficient. (I was just using one image to do a sanity check)

Comment: What's your `inputs.shape`, `outputs.shape` and `bce_dice` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your model architecture its looks like you are retaining the original image dimension, so looking at it your label should be of dimension `(256,256,4)` 
As keras always except 4 dimensional tensor while training ,so your Y_train should of following dimensions

```
Y_train = [batch_size,img_height,img_width,number_of_classes]
```

After looking at the error dimension (1, 65536, 4) your passing

```
1 = batch_size ,65536 flattened image and 4 = num_of_classes
```

the `65536` should be reshaped to `(256, 256)`

So Y_train would be

```
Y_train = [1,256,256,4]
```

if you want to flatten the image you can flatten the image in the model by using

```
from keras import backend as K
K.flatten()
```

so you should change the code where you read the image and perform flatten operation and instead maintain the spatial dimension of the image.

And also other observation
the layer where you define your number of output classes

```
outputs = Conv2DTranspose(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
```

that should be

```
outputs = Conv2DTranspose(4, (1, 1), activation='softmax') (c9)
#as you have 4 output classes
```

Comment: The model seems to train, but after that, `model.load_weights('model-dsbowl2018-1.h5')` doesn't seem to work. I've updated the question